# "poll called with fds buffer too small" with link time optimization (-flto)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, gcc

Suddenly started getting this error at link time on some older code. I managed to replicate the problem with a very simple snippet of code:

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    struct pollfd m_fds[6000];
    nfds_t m_count;
} PollWrapper;
static PollWrapper g_pollWrapper;

int main()
{
    return poll(g_pollWrapper.m_fds, g_pollWrapper.m_count, 0);
}
```

Compiling without -flto is fine.

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -o poll.exe poll.c # gcc 4.8.1-10ubuntu9
# successful
```

But adding -flto causes an error when linking:

```
gcc -Wall -O3 -flto -o poll.exe poll.c # gcc 4.8.1-10ubuntu9
# error
gcc -Wall -O3 -flto -o poll.o -o poll.c
# compilation is fine
gcc -Wall -O3 -flto -o poll.exe poll.o
# linking fails

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h: In function `main`:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h:41:2: warning: call to `__poll_chk_warn` > declared with attribute warning: poll called with fds buffer too small file nfds entries [enabled by default]
 return __poll_chk (__fds, __nfds, __timeout, __bos (__fds));
 ^
```

Having read related questions, I tried explicitly enabling and disabling the linker plugin, neither had any effect.

This only appears to happen with an array, none of the following have the same problem:

```
struct pollfd f;
int numfds = poll(&f, g_pollWrapper.m_size, duration);
```

or

```
struct pollfd fds[6000];
int numfds = poll(&f, g_pollWrapper.m_size, duration);
```

etc.

Am I either missing something obvious or is this an LTO defect in my GCC, and if so is there a way I can work around it?

Comment: I don't observe that GCC bug on my Debian/Sid/x86-64 with `gcc version 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-10)`; so upgrade to GCC 4.8.2

Comment: No problem with gcc 4.8.3 (s20131212), FreeBSD 9.2/amd64.

Comment: Take a look at http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html (release notes for 4.8.2).  `Link-time optimization (LTO) improvements:
LTO partitioning has been rewritten for better reliability and maintanibility. Several important bugs leading to link failures have been fixed.`

Comment: Excellent, I'll try it on later GCCs and if the problem goes away I guess I can annotate it in the code and stop worrying about compile-with-specific-build :)